# Paint Icon with win32api c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to paint an Icon onto my window with the win32 api. Here is where I load the image.

```
case WM_CREATE: {
        HANDLE image = (HICON)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("Button.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
break;
}
```

Here is where I try to paint the icon onto the screen.

```
    case WM_NCPAINT: {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        BITMAP bm;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(ParentHwnd, &ps);
        HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hbmOld = SelectObject(hdcMem, image);

        GetObject(image, sizeof(bm), &bm);

        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);
        EndPaint(ParentHwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
```

For some reason, I get this error on SelectObject();

```
E0144 a value of type "HGDIOBJ" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "HBITMAP"
```

I'm using Visual Studio community 2019. I've looked all over the place for an answer. Thank you in advance for your efforts to help.

Comment: You could just load the icon into a static control via the [WM_SETICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-seticon) message.  Otherwise there is the [DrawIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawicon) function

Comment: I think you need at least replace `WM_NCPAINT` with `WM_PAINT`. The `WM_NCPAINT` message is for advanced usage. Also you don't check if `LoadImage` succeeds.

Comment: You're supposed to just cast HGDIOBJ to HBITMAP. However, that is *not* your main problem here.

Comment: Icons are easy, you just call DrawIcon.  No need for all the hoops that you have to jump through to draw a bitmap.

Comment: Thank You all so much. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One, you are not supposed to use `BeginPaint()` in a `WM_NCPAINT` handler, only in a `WM_PAINT` handler. Per the [`WM_NCPAINT` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-ncpaint), use [`GetDCEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdcex) instead.

Two, you likely have [STRICT Type Checking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-type-checking) turned on (which is a good thing), that is why you are getting the compiler error.  Under `STRICT`, an `HGDIOBJ` (aka `void*`) cannot be assigned to an `HBITMAP` (aka `struct HBITMAP__*`), so you would need to explicitly type-cast the return value of `SelectObject()`. However, you are loading an `HICON`, which you can't select as-is into an `HDC`, so you will have to either:

- load a BMP file instead of an ICO file.
- convert the `HICON` data to an actual `HBITMAP`.
- use [`DrawIcon()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawicon) or [`DrawIconEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawiconex).

Three, in your `WM_CREATE` handler, your `image` variable is local to that message handler, so whatever `image` you are accessing in the `WM_NCPAINT` handler is not the same variable.

Try this instead:

```cpp
HBITMAP image;
...

case WM_CREATE: {
    HICON icon = (HICON) LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("Button.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
    // convert icon to image as needed...
    DestroyIcon(icon);
    break;
}

case WM_NCPAINT: {
    BITMAP bm;
    HDC hdc = GetDCEx(hwnd, (HRGN)wParam, DCX_WINDOW | DCX_INTERSECTRGN);
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, image);
    GetObject(image, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    break;
}
```

Or this:

```cpp
HICON image;
...

case WM_CREATE: {
    image = (HICON) LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("Button.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
    break;
}

case WM_DESTROY: {
    DestroyIcon(image);
    break;
}

case WM_NCPAINT: {
    HDC hdc = GetDCEx(hwnd, (HRGN)wParam, DCX_WINDOW|DCX_INTERSECTRGN);
    DrawIcon(hdc, 0, 0, image);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I was completely oblivious to the existence of DrawIcon().